# Adding props condition in Styled component gives me an error of "Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a condition using the component's `disabled` prop. However, I'm getting this error `Adding props condition in Styled component error Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.` The code below works on other component, except for this one.

Can you please help me understand what the error means or what's the fix of it? TIA!

ListGroupItem is a react-bootstrap component.

My typescript version is 4.4.4

```
export const StyledListGroupItem = styled(ListGroupItem)`
  ${({ disabled }) => (disabled && `
    color: red;
  `)};
` as any;
```